# VB Macro - Create CSV file by copying relevant data from different spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba

i don't write on VB, but i need a script to do some work for me. if someone could help...
I have a folder1 with excel files in it.
I have a Additional1 sheet with some additional data.

1. I need a macro to go thru folder1 reading files and copying certain columns into a CSV file (can be a new or using template) with certain headers in first row.
2. Then looking by a cat number in Additional1 copy some additional data from certain columns
3. and then saving this new CSV under the name which can be found under a specific header in the excel file which we are reading from folder1.

here is the content of one of the files from folder1

```
Aritst  Year    Manufacturer UPC    Catalog No  Track # Track Name
Blackfield  2007    8.02645E+11     KSCOPE126M  1       Once
Blackfield  2007    8.02645E+11     KSCOPE126M  2       Bla People
Blackfield  2007    8.02645E+11     KSCOPE126M  3       Miss U
Blackfield  2007    8.02645E+11     KSCOPE126M  4       Christenings
```

Say I need only

A, B, D and F columns copied to

K, E, A and AD

of the CSV file correspondingly (i.e. CSV Column A will contain data of column D of opened spreadsheet - in above example Catalog No)

here is the code I've got:

```
Sub Convert_to_Digi()

  ' First delete existing data
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim SrcWkb As Workbook
  Dim StartRow As Long
  Dim wkbname As Variant
  Dim xlsFiles As Variant
  Dim MyRange As Variant
  Dim NewName As Variant

    StartRow = 2

' Get the workbooks to open
    xlsFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xls), *.xls", MultiSelect:=True)
      If VarType(xlsFiles) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub

     ' Loop through each workbook and copy the data to this CSV
      For Each wkbname In xlsFiles
        Set SrcWkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wkbname, ReadOnly:=True)
            MyRange = Sheets("export_label_conf").Range("A:A")
            LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyRange)
            Sheets("export_label_conf").Select
            NewName = Cells(3, 2) & ".csv"

            If LastRow >= StartRow Then

                ' copy column D data
                With SrcWkb.Worksheets("export_label_conf")
                    .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D").LastRow).Copy

                    SrcWkb.Worksheets("export_label_conf").Select
                    Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Select
                    Selection.Copy

                    ' paste into CSV template file
                    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\DIGITAL\template.csv", ReadOnly:=False
                    Range("A2").Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                        :=False, Transpose:=False

                End With

                ' and save template as new CSV with barcode as name
                Name = CurDir & "\" & NewName
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                    Name, FileFormat:= _
                    xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            End If

        SrcWkb.Close
      Next wkbname

End Sub
```

I'm stuck with copying multiple columns at once into CSV file... and generally not sure if the script is written correctly =)
can someone give me a hand on this please?

---

**UPDATE 28.02.11 11:23**

epic fail on trying to implement vlookup =)

'vlookup additional data from a spreadsheet

```
    Dim FndStr As String
    Dim FndVal As Range
    Dim addWkb As Variant
    Dim AddInfo As String

    ' copy column E
    FndStr = MyRange.Columns(12).Value

    Set addWkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\DIGITAL\Snapper Owned  Licensed Catalogue.xls", ReadOnly:=True)

    Set FndVal = Columns("B:B").Find(What:=FndStr, LookAt:=xlWhole)
       If FndVal Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox "ID not found!!"
       Else
            'get value of column D
            AddInfo = FndVal.Offset(0, 3).Value
       End If

    ' paste into CSV template file, ADDITIONAL INFO into AO column
    csvWkb.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 41).PasteSpecial Paste:=AddInfo, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

i pasted this before "and save template as new CSV with barcode as name" in Chris's code edit... Help please? how do i loop thru the column and vlookup each value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding copy of multiple columns, it is possible (eg `Range("A2:A4,B2:B4,D2:D4,F2:F4").Copy` ), but when you paste them they will be in a continuous range - better to just copy separately

I've re-factored your code give you some hints

```
Sub Convert_to_Digi()

    ' First delete existing data
    Dim SrcWkb As Workbook
    Dim csvWkb As Workbook
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim wkbname As Variant
    Dim xlsFiles As Variant
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim NewName As Variant
    Dim csvName As String

    StartRow = 2

    ' Get the workbooks to open
    xlsFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xls), *.xls", MultiSelect:=True)
    If VarType(xlsFiles) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub

    ' Loop through each workbook and copy the data to this CSV
     For Each wkbname In xlsFiles
        Set SrcWkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wkbname, ReadOnly:=False)
        Set srcSheet = SrcWkb.Worksheets("export_label_conf")

        ' Get used range on sheet
        Set MyRange = srcSheet.UsedRange
        ' Adjust to exclude top row
        Set MyRange = MyRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(MyRange.Rows.Count - 1)

        NewName = srcSheet.Cells(3, 2) & ".csv"

        If MyRange.Row + MyRange.Rows.Count - 1 >= StartRow Then
            Set csvWkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\DIGITAL\template.csv", ReadOnly:=False)

            ' copy column A
            MyRange.Columns(1).Copy
            ' paste into CSV template file, column K
            csvWkb.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            ' copy column B
            MyRange.Columns(4).Copy
            ' paste into CSV template file
            csvWkb.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            ' copy column D
            MyRange.Columns(4).Copy
            ' paste into CSV template file, column A
            csvWkb.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            ' copy column F
            MyRange.Columns(6).Copy
            ' paste into CSV template file, column AD
            csvWkb.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 30).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            ' and save template as new CSV with barcode as name
            csvName = CurDir & "\" & NewName '  using CurDir is a bit dangerous: how do you know what its set to?
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csvName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        End If

        SrcWkb.Close
    Next wkbname

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you Chris for looking into this!
i won't use CurDir as you suggested. i just going to set it to constant destination.
sorry i couldn't get to PC earlier.. i'm going to test it and feed back to you!

Comment: wooohoo! code worked! from the first instance!
now i need to add vlookup from additional spreadsheet. i found the following code online:
`Sub Find()
Dim FndStr As String
Dim FndVal As Range
FndStr = Application.InputBox("Enter ID No.", "Search ID")

     Set FndVal = Columns("A:A").Find(What:=FndStr, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If FndVal Is Nothing Then
           MsgBox "ID not found!!"
        Else
            MsgBox "Staff Location is " & FndVal.Offset(0, 1).Value & _
            Chr(13) & "Time is " & Format(FndVal.Offset(0, 2).Value, "HH:MM")
        End If
End Sub`
which im going to try now

Comment: Have no luck with implementing vlookup... =(